# Latest research on suffix arrays vs suffix trees

Tags: suffix-tree, suffix-array

I've been trying to ascertain whether suffix trees or suffix arrays (including their variants) are more space efficient (amongst other properties as given below), but I seem to be coming up with different viewpoints depending on where I look. This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), for example, suggests that suffix arrays are more space efficient. In [this book](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=LJbfP29Xz4QC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=suffix+tree+memory+space&source=bl&ots=yfprCuZ5xz&sig=dD2oXdSu93Yux-jEdNb19znJyRE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4dq6Uow6w8CQBbCagIAL&ved=0CCgQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=suffix%20tree%20memory%20space&f=false), in section 1.6, it is suggested that (compressed) suffix trees are very efficient for space, based on the paper "Compressed Suﬃx Trees with Full Functionality" by Kunihiko Sadakane. So what is the latest research on the comparison between suffix trees and suffix arrays (including their variants)? More specifically, I am interested in knowing which is better in terms of i) construction, ii) space (theoretical and practical), iii) querying performance.

I know that portions of this question may have been asked previously, but those questions are at least a year old and I am interested in the latest research.